# Python 2.7: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON file with a structure like this:

```
{
 "some": "data",
 "some2": [
           {
            "some3": "data3",
            "some4": {
                      "some5": "data5",
                      "some6": {
                                "some7": "data7",
                                "some8": {
                                          "some9": "data9",
                                          "somedata": [0, 100, 200, 300, 400]}}}}]}
```

I parsed it using json.load(). Let it be:

```
 parsedjson = json.load(myjsonfile)
```

When I try processing "somedata" values

```
 parsedjson['some2']['some4']['some6']['some8']['somedata']
```

Python throws an exception "`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`"

I really can't understand why is this happening and how can I solve it. I checked few other questions on stackoverflow but no luck.

Comment: "some2" has a list as value

Comment: I pretty-formatted your JSON and now the problem it should jump out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**'some2'** has list as value. You can either iterate over it or use index to access the value.

**EX:**

```
parsedjson  = {"some":"data","some2":[{"some3":"data3","some4":{"some5":"data5","some6":{
"some7":"data7","some8":{"some9":"data9","somedata":[0,100,200,300,400]}}}}]}
print parsedjson['some2'][0]['some4']['some6']['some8']['somedata']  #Using index 0
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)